# Cant perform edit when primary key is float?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, floating-point, action, edit

I am using an existing external database which has primary key set has floating/double. All actions work fine except for edit.

The error it gives is this.
Is there a way around this or changing it to int is the only way?

> No route matches [GET] "/subsystem_tbls/'1.123'/edit"

#### Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "subsystem_tbls#index"
  resources :subsystem_tbls
  resources :ui_types_tbls
  resources :cmd_types_tbls
end
```

#### Controller

```
class SubsystemTblsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @subs = SUBSYSTEM_TBL.all
  end

  def new
    @subs = SUBSYSTEM_TBL.new
  end

  def show
    @subs = SUBSYSTEM_TBL.find_by(params[:SUBSYSTEM_ID])
  end

  def edit
    @subs = SUBSYSTEM_TBL.find_by(params[:SUBSYSTEM_ID])
  end

  def create
    @subs = SUBSYSTEM_TBL.new(sub_params)
    if @subs.save
      redirect_to @subs
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @subs = SUBSYSTEM_TBL.find_by(params[:SUBSYSTEM_ID])
    if @subs.update_attributes(sub_params)
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    SUBSYSTEM_TBL.find_by(params[:SUBSYSTEM_ID]).destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

  def sub_params
    params.require(:subsystem_tbl).permit(:SUBSYSTEM_ID, :SUBSYSTEM_NAME)
  end
end
```

## Rake ROutes

```
root_path   GET     /   

subsystem_tbls#index
subsystem_tbls_path     GET     /subsystem_tbls(.:format)   

subsystem_tbls#index
    POST    /subsystem_tbls(.:format)   

subsystem_tbls#create
new_subsystem_tbl_path  GET     /subsystem_tbls/new(.:format)   

subsystem_tbls#new
edit_subsystem_tbl_path     GET     /subsystem_tbls/:id/edit(.:format)  

subsystem_tbls#edit
subsystem_tbl_path  GET     /subsystem_tbls/:id(.:format)   

subsystem_tbls#show
    PATCH   /subsystem_tbls/:id(.:format)   

subsystem_tbls#update
    PUT     /subsystem_tbls/:id(.:format)   

subsystem_tbls#update
    DELETE  /subsystem_tbls/:id(.:format)   

subsystem_tbls#destroy
```

Comment: *Why* is your primary key a float?

Comment: @JordanRunning Thing is its like a version column, ex 1.0023.

Comment: And i cant make changes to the database

Comment: so i cant eh?....

Comment: It's really unfortunate that you can't change the database, because a float is the wrong data type for a version number, [for several reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate). You want a string, decimal (iif you're certain you'll only have major.minor), or even [multiple integer/string columns](https://github.com/semver/semver/issues/79). You're not totally out of luck, though. I'll write up an answer if no one else beats me to it.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Wow, I can't get my head around this code.  Where is `params[:SUBSYSTEM_ID]` defined?  It should just be `params[:id]` Can you show your `rake routes` ?

Comment: @JordanRunning I tried changing it to string, still no luck. I'm sure even with the change to a decimal notation i'll encounter the same problem.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I am using an external database with all column and table name in uppercase

Comment: @gundergobi that does not mean your routes will generate in this fashion try `params[:id]` instead. If you are unsure about this run rake routes and I would guess you will see routes like "subsystem_tbls/:id" the `:id` portion is what you are referencing

Comment: @engineersmnky, i have made modifications as you have specified. Yet the same error on edit

Comment: And in doing so you have proved @SteveTurczyn and my point `params[:SUBSYSTEM_ID]` should be `params[:id]` now that being said I am unsure why you have a routing issue other than it appears to be placing single quotes into your route.

Comment: Now its showing this: No route matches [GET] "/subsystem_tbls/1.123/edit" yet if i manually change the 1.123 in the url to 1 its gets into the edit page perfectly. @engineersmnky

Comment: @engineersmnky my thoughts exactly. And yea since i'm testing there is only one record as of now.

Comment: Yeah I am not sure I can help other than to suggest a schema change maybe @JordanRunning can as mentioned in a comment above

Comment: I'll check with the schema change with my superiors, and @engineersmnky if you don't mind i have question for you. How hard is it to implement github style search and filtering mechanism in rails and i don't have a clue about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165503/discussion-between-engineersmnky-and-gunder-gobi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any datatypes which includes a decimal point as a primary key is not suitable for rails.